# NSImage acting weird

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, image, nsimage

Why is this code setting artistImage to an image with 0 width and 0 height?

> NSURL *artistImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/8581581.jpg"];
>       NSImage *artistImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:artistImageURL];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSImage does load this fine for me, but that particular image has corrupt metadata.  Its resolution according to the exif data is 7.1999997999228071e-06 dpi.

NSImage respects the DPI info in the file, so if you try to draw the image at its natural size, you'll get something 2520000070 pixels across.

Answer (score 4):

As Ken wrote, the DPI is messed up in this image. If you want to force NSImage to set the real image size (ignoring the DPI), use the method described at http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=NSImage:

```
NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[image representations] objectAtIndex: 0];
NSSize size = NSMakeSize([rep pixelsWide], [rep pixelsHigh]);
[image setSize: size];
```

Comment: This is not safe in general.  That's an unsafe cast to NSBitmapImageRep.  For example, an arbitrary image might be a PDF backed, in which case pixelsWide and pixelsHigh would return  NSImageRepMatchesDevice indicating that the rep is resolution independent.  NSImageRepMatchesDevice == 0.

Comment: That's good to know... but for standard web images (png, gif, jpg) this shouldn't happen, right?

Comment: No, there's no promise about what type would be used - this is a pure unsafe type cast.  The primary reason this would change would be if NSBitmapImageRep was deprecated in favor of a new rep subclass that was a tighter match to CGImage.  Then people who explicitly were instantiating NSBitmapImageRep would get it for compat, but not people who were just making NSImages like this.

Comment: So I suppose it should be fine then to wrap this in an "if" and only call the code if the representation at 0 is a NSBitmapImageRep (which should work in 99.9% cases), and leave the image as it is if it happens to have a different representation?

Comment: If you want to do that, don't look for NSBitmapImageRep, just handle the case of the pixelWidth or pixelHeight being NSImageRepMatchesDevice.

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked, `NSImage's` `-initWithContentsOfURL:` only works with file URLs.  You'll need to retrieve the URL first, and then use `-initWithData:`

Comment: Also worth noting that it's never a good idea to use any of the `-initWithContentsOfURL:` methods from the main thread as they will block the main event loop. Use an asynchronous `NSURLConnection` object to create an `NSData` object and notify on completion instead.

Comment: NSImage can load from the network.  Yes on Rob's point, though.

Answer (score 0):

It is more or less guaranteed that .representations contains NSImageRep* (of course not always NSBitmapImageRep). To be on a safe side for future extensions one can write something like code below. And it also takes into account multiple representation (like in some .icns and .tiff files).

```
@implementation NSImage (Extension)

- (void) makePixelSized {
    NSSize max = NSZeroSize;
    for (NSObject* o in self.representations) {
        if ([o isKindOfClass: NSImageRep.class]) {
            NSImageRep* r = (NSImageRep*)o;
            if (r.pixelsWide != NSImageRepMatchesDevice && r.pixelsHigh != NSImageRepMatchesDevice) {
                max.width = MAX(max.width, r.pixelsWide);
                max.height = MAX(max.height, r.pixelsHigh);
            }
        }
    }
    if (max.width > 0 && max.height > 0) {
        self.size = max;
    }
}

@end
```